# Return value not being picked up in anther return payload

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an issue where a function that returns a value is not being pulled through in another function. Here is my code

```js
public _getProfileToUpdate() {
  return {
    corporateId: this.storeService.setStoreData().profile.preferred_username[1],
    id: this.storeService.setStoreData().profile.sub,
    firstName: this.userFormGroup.controls.firstName.value,
    lastName: this.userFormGroup.controls.lastName.value,
    email: this.userFormGroup.controls.email.value,
    mobile: this.userFormGroup.controls.mobile.value,
    workNumber: this.userFormGroup.controls.workNumber.value,
    roleId: this.sortRoleId()
  };
}

sortRoleId() {
  this._contentService._getRoles().subscribe((resp) => {
    const search = this.storeService.setStoreData().profile.role;
    const index = Object.values(resp.roles).indexOf(search);
    const result = Object.keys(resp.roles)[index];
    return result;
  })
}
```

So there is a "result" value that I am trying to send to the "roleId" value in the other function but it is showing as undefined.

Comment: That's because `_contentService._getRoles()` is an async function and thus the return inside `_getProfileToUpdate()` won't wait for its subscription. Hence it will returned as `undefined`.

Comment: ok so how do I alter this then?

Comment: Is it okay to combine the functions?

Comment: yes that is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public _getProfileToUpdate() {
    // Service call
    this._contentService._getRoles().subscribe((resp) => {
        const search = this.storeService.setStoreData().profile.role;
        const index = Object.values(resp.roles).indexOf(search);
        const result = Object.keys(resp.roles)[index];
        // Return object
        return {
            corporateId: this.storeService.setStoreData().profile.preferred_username[1],
            id: this.storeService.setStoreData().profile.sub,
            firstName: this.userFormGroup.controls.firstName.value,
            lastName: this.userFormGroup.controls.lastName.value,
            email: this.userFormGroup.controls.email.value,
            mobile: this.userFormGroup.controls.mobile.value,
            workNumber: this.userFormGroup.controls.workNumber.value,
            roleId: result
        };
    })
}
```

Comment: if you call _getProfileToUpdate() probably does not return anything until the request is resolved

Comment: @Daniel That's true. It is the expected behavior I guess. The response from service call is required to populate the object field.

Comment: @skydev Does it meet your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I would subscribe to the content service in your ngOnInit or i would change the calling hierarchy of your methodes like:

```
profile = {};
   public _getProfileToUpdate() {
 this._contentService._getRoles().subscribe((resp) => {
 const search = this.storeService.setStoreData().profile.role;
        const index = Object.values(resp.roles).indexOf(search);
        const result = Object.keys(resp.roles)[index];
        // Return object
        this.profile = {
            corporateId: this.storeService.setStoreData().profile.preferred_username[1],
            id: this.storeService.setStoreData().profile.sub,
            firstName: this.userFormGroup.controls.firstName.value,
            lastName: this.userFormGroup.controls.lastName.value,
            email: this.userFormGroup.controls.email.value,
            mobile: this.userFormGroup.controls.mobile.value,
            workNumber: this.userFormGroup.controls.workNumber.value,
            roleId: result
        };
    })
}
```

You pass the variable arround in your form or whatever and as soon as it gets updated angular recalls the functions needed to process your information.